# Yii application redirecting to online version

Tags: php, yii

I have a Yii application on an external server which I have since pulled down. I am trying to develop on localhost but every-time I open "localhost/applicationExample" my application redirects back to where it was hosted "www.applicationExample.com"

I've tried looking in the "/opt/lampp/htdocs/applicationExample/protected/config/main.php" file, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Any help?

Comment: sharing `config/main.php` could help you!

Comment: show us the `index` method of `siteController`

Comment: Check your default controller & action (could be actionIndex) to see what happening. Maybe someone expected that the site would be redirected to url that has www. prefix